# Mysql, get the most recent values of each 2 columns pair

Tags: mysql

Here is a simple table

[image: table]

I would like to return only the most recent by creation_date) unique pair of item_key and category_key

In this case request should return the line 1,3,4.
1, 3 because it's an unique pair and 4 because the line are most recent pair of ["titi" and 3] then the line 3

here my expected result :

[image: result]

I use mysql 5.7 database.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You should always post data as text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention which version of MySQL you are using, so I'll assume it's a modern one (MySQL 8.x).

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by item_key, category_key 
                      order by creation_date desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

**EDIT for MySQL 5.x**:

In MySQL 5.x you can do:

```
select *
from t
where (item_key, category_key, creation_date) in (
  select item_key, category_key, max(creation_date)
  from t
  group by item_key, category_key
)
```

Comment: This work perfectly on 8.x yes. but yeah, i'm mysql 5.7 on my production =/ can i replace the row_number() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by an max

```
SELECT MAX(`creation_date`), `item_key`, `category_key`, `the_value`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `item_key`, `category_key`
```

Comment: I already try this but it' not working. i will have my 3 lines with good dates but the value and ID will be different. it will display "value2" instead of "value4"